# Making a non-child div appear as a child div

Tags: html, css

I want to place 2 divs on my page such ***it looks*** that the 2nd div is inside the 1st one. Also the 1st div should react to the growing size of <strike>1st</strike> second.

But in the code they shouldn't have parent-child relationship(i.e, **2nd div not really inside the 1st div tags**).

I don't want 2nd div to be placed inside 1st because I am updating the 1st div via ajax and the second should remain intact.

Would prefer a pure CSS solution if there exists any..

[image]

Comment: This is definitely a CSS question, not a javascript question.

Comment: Why can't you place the second inside the first and just keep it intact when replacing the content of the first? Replacing content isn't necessarily an all or nothing operation.

Answer (score 2):

Use `position:absolute;` on the 2nd div.

Comment: would the 1st div react to the grown up size of 2nd ?

Comment: @Marcos - Nope. The 2 will be as unrelated as I am to you ;)

Comment: @Joseph yes..and that's what the problem is... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 HTML :

<div id="container">
    <div id="div1">Div 1</div>
    <div id="div2">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#div1 {
    min-height:200px;
    border:3px solid black;
}
#div2 {
    min-height:100px;
    border:3px solid black;
    position: relative;
    top: -150px;
    left: 1%;
    width:97%;
}
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/kkJZR/